# Overloading ostream << operator

Tags: c++

I've got an **immutable** header:

```
typedef class Foo
{
    public:
         friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Foo&);
}*pFoo, **ppFoo;
```

I'm trying to implement the operator like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Foo.h"

ostream& operator<<(ostream& a, Foo& b){
     a << endl;
     return a;
}
```

This is throwing these errors:

```
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   (foo.h)

Error   5   error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters    (foo.h)
Error   2   error C2433: 'ostream' : 'friend' not permitted on data declarations (foo.h)
Error   4   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream' (foo.h)
```

Keeping in mind that the header can't be touched, what can I do?

Comment: Seems like you're missing some `#include` statements. Also your _"implementation"_  looks pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

If that is the entire header, then it is broken. It is missing `#include <ostream>` and `std::`.

Since you can't change it, you'll have to:

- complain bitterly
- include `<ostream>` and `using namespace std` before inclusion (you're already almost doing this)

As of C++11, including `<iostream>` is actually enough and, [as it happens, with my compiler I cannot reproduce your problem with C++03 either](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c525bfe89383b71). But in C++03 it is *possible* that you need to separately `#include <ostream>` (the former is not guaranteed to include the latter) and that's all I can guess at from the limited information provided.

Comment: How's that different from `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Extremely so, pre-C++11.

Comment: Neither <iostream> or <ostream> works. Since you can't reproduce the problem, I'm beginning to wonder if this is an environmental issue.

Comment: @TheFaster: In that case yes